# Replace string with field in .docx document for all .docx files in a given directory

Tags: c#, vba, powershell, ms-word, mailmerge

There are ways to find and replace text across multiple .docx documents, as described e.g. here:

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/word/1002-word-replace-multiple-files.html

The case I'm attempting to execute is similar to that in the link with one small difference, viz. that I'm attempting to replace a string with a field.

For example, I'd like to replace the string

[[6] or [12] months]

with

`{MERGEFIELD "preexisting_condition_limit"}`

where the latter isn't a string, but a field, i.e. what word creates an empty instance of when one presses ctrl + f9.

I've tried PowerShell, C#, and Visual Basic primarily for their interoperability, but any programming language works.

Comment: Start the macro recorder, and then go through the steps of adding a field. Stop the macro recorder and look at the macro source. This usually gives you a place to get started.

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you add the following macro to a new document and add the required field to the body of that document:

```
Sub UpdateDocuments()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim strFolder As String, strFile As String, strDocNm As String, wdDoc As Document
strFolder = GetFolder
If strFolder = "" Then Exit Sub
ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = True
With ActiveDocument
  strDocNm = .FullName
  .Range.Fields(1).Copy
End With
strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.doc", vbNormal)
Do While strFile <> ""
  If strFolder & "\" & strFile <> strDocNm Then
    Set wdDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=strFolder & "\" & strFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
    With wdDoc
      With .Range.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = "String to find"
        .Replacement.Text = "^c"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
      End With
      .Close SaveChanges:=True
    End With
  End If
  strFile = Dir()
Loop
Set wdDoc = Nothing
ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function GetFolder() As String
Dim oFolder As Object
GetFolder = ""
Set oFolder = CreateObject("Shell.Application").BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose a folder", 0)
If (Not oFolder Is Nothing) Then GetFolder = oFolder.Items.Item.Path
Set oFolder = Nothing
End Function
```

**Note:** There is no such field type as 'MAILMERGE' in Word. Your {MAILMERGE "preexisting_condition_limit"} field refers.